# trouble with first try at renderItem to change response items in jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have read a bunch of SO answers about using _renderItem to modify the Autocomplete dropdown responses, and I copied some code from them.  But it doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

The code below is a simplified concept test. When certain large cities are entered, I want to change the city response (from geonames.org) and offer responses that are boroughs/regions of that city. The concept test simply changes "New York" to "Bronx, New York, Bronx County, New York" with a text string for Bronx and existing data elements. This will eventually get more complex, but I just want to get the basics going, first.

Geonames.org serves up "New York" when the first few letters go in, but no override change occurs, and the alert does not fire.  I also get the Firebug error - ReferenceError: item is not defined }).data("item.autocomplete", item)._renderItem=  Though I see .data("item.autocomplete", item) in lots of examples, this one generates an error, and the error just changes when I tinker with changes.  There is something here I do not understand. At least 2 symptoms occur - the Firebug not defined error, and the fact that the if statement is not executing.

The code is as follows. What should change?

```
$("#city3").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response){
        //some lines omitted
        $.ajax(
            success: function (data){
                response( $.map(data.geonames, function (item){
                    return {
                        label: item.name + (item.adminName2 ? ", " + item.adminName2 : "") + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                        value: item.name + (item.adminName2 ? ", " + item.adminName2 : "") + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : ""),
                        county: item.adminName2
                        }
                    }));
            }
        //some lines omitted
}).data("item.autocomplete", item)._renderItem=
    function(ul,item){
    //simple test
        if(item.label=="New York"){
            alert("NYC triggered");
            var replaceItem = $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a>"+"Bronx"+item.label+"Bronx County"+item.adminName1+"</a>");
                return replaceItem.appendTo(ul);
        }else{
        return item.label;
        }
    };
```

Comment: can you link to some of the answers / "lots of examples" which you have based this code on? `item` isn't just a magic word, it's a variable, which needs to be defined before it can be passed as an argument to a function (in this case, the function is `.data(...)`). Some light googling leads me to believe that the line in question should actually read: `}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem=`, ie: overwriting the `_renderItem` function in the `autocomplete` data. Note that this is a "private"/undocumented method, so it may break in the future.

Comment: @WillPalmer thanks. Yes, I've seen the form you mention, and sometimes both forms are in the same code chunk. This is the part I don't understand. In my case, "autocomplete" in either or both of the .data expressions causes Autocomplete to break. I get no dropdown at all with any number of characters typed in. It does remove the Firebug error, but Autocomplete is broken and so no append occurs. I Googled "jQuery Autocomplete renderItem" and read maybe 30 entries. Both forms inside .data() are used, and the reason is not clear to me.

Comment: @WillPalmer thanks for getting new thoughts going in my head. I started with another piece of working code that begins with }).data("autocomplete") - as you noted. The Firebug errors went away and some very simple test exercises worked.  I also found that the replaceItem function I wrote does just that. It replaces the entire dropdown with 1 item - not what I wanted. So I still don't understand the entries in the .data(), but I am off on a more productive avenue.  Thanks again.